# Running wp7 app on the device in Windows 8

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-8, windows-phone-8, zune

I am developing a small windows phone application and it work fine when i run in the emulator. my problem is that i wanted to test in my device that. since am using windows 8. and in windows 8 zune cannot be installed ( each time it show an error due to .NET 3.5 cannot be installed). someone please tell me how can i test in my device my application or a way to install zune in windows 8.

what i have done:
1. I tried to install zune many times everytime the same Error(Cannont download .NET 3.5).
2. Tried to turn "ON" the .NET 3.5 feature. result was the same.

i found that zune was no more using(changed to xbox music and dont know what that will do).Is there any way i can test my app on my device?

if none of these going to work is there any alternative option?

Comment: get a copy of virtualbox, run a virtual win7/xp and install zune in that.

Comment: @MarcB no other way to do this in windows 8. Am using windows phone 8 SDK.

Comment: Zune runs on windows 8 just fine for me

Comment: @Jesse zune was running for me also when i was using windows 8 RP. now i have the windows 8 original, i mean the final version and i cannot install zune anymore

Comment: @Jesse the reason for that is it need .NET 3.5 , and it not able to download and install. i tried many times and many ways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have your installation CD or the image loaded use this in command prompt
Example :

`dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFX3 /Source:G:\sources\sxs /LimitAccess`  
1. run this command as Administrator 
2. Instead of G: give your drive where you have the installation Disc

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Control Pannel > Programs and Features > Turn Windows Features On or Off > Check .NET 3.5

After you are done with that, install the Zune software and you should be good to go.

Comment: as i have mentioned in the question, problem is that it cannot download .NET 3.5 from the windows update. same thing is happening when i turn ON the feature.